# loop through several listbox vba

Tags: excel, for-loop, listbox, vba

I have the following code, off course it is not working, but I hope it suggests my intentions.

```
Dim lItem As Long
Dim input_sh As Worksheet
Dim lb As ListBox
Set input_sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
    For i = 1 To 4
        lb = "ListBox" & i
        For lItem = 0 To lb.ListCount - 1
            If lb.Selected(lItem) = True Then
                input_sh.Cells(1, 14 + i) = lb.List(lItem)
                lb.Selected(lItem) = False
            End If
        Next lItem
    Next i
```

Basically I have 4 listbox in an userform and would to use a for loop to get the selected items, instead of having a for loop for each listbox.

Comment: Have you tried looping in the `.Controls` collection of the form?

Comment: no i haven't should say i am very much a beginner :-(

Comment: `Set lb = Me.Controls("ListBox" & i)`

Comment: @TimWilliams yeah I meant *have you tried pulling your `ListBox` from the form's `.Controls` collection* - that's the answer! @fabio notice the `Set` keyword in the assignment of `lb`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is answered in the comments, but just so as to make it one less unanswered question in the stack (and eventually in the *close votes* stack):

```
Dim input_sh As Worksheet
Dim lb As ListBox

Set input_sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
For i = 1 To 4

    Set lb = Controls("ListBox" & i)

    ' object "lb" now contains a reference to the appropriate ListBox control.
    ' (do something with lb)

Next i
```

This is one of the differences between VB6 and VBA: you can't have a *control array* in VBA. In VB6 you could have named all ListBoxes, say `MyListBox`, and given them an *index* between 1 and 4, making the code look like this:

```
Dim lb As ListBox

For i = 1 To 4

    Set lb = MyListBox(i)

    ' object "lb" now contains a reference to the appropriate ListBox control.
    ' (do something with lb)

Next i
```